# Split a list evenly

Tags: code-golf, array

You are given a list of at least two positive integers as input. The challenge is to find such a position of a cut that minimizes the absolute difference between the sums of the two parts (to the left and to the right of it). The position should be given as the index of the first element after the cut.

This is tagged [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins!

### Test cases

These are 0-indexed.

```
[1, 2, 3] -> 2
[3, 2, 1] -> 1
[1, 5, 3, 2, 4] -> 2 or 3
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16] -> 4
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1] -> 2 or 3
[1, 2, 4, 8, 14] -> 4
```

For example, for the first test case, if the cut is placed before the second element, the sums of the parts will be 1 and 5 and the absolute difference will be 4, and if the cut is placed before the third element, the sums will be equal and the absolute difference will be 0. Therefore, the correct output is 2 (assuming 0-indexing). If multiple correct outputs exist, you must output one of them.

### Explained examples

Input: `[1, 2, 3]`

```
Cut at 0: [] vs [1, 2, 3] -> 0 vs 1+2+3=6, difference is 6
Cut at 1: [1] vs [2, 3] -> 1 vs 2+3=5, difference is 4
Cut at 2: [1, 2] vs [3] -> 1+2=3 vs 3, difference is 0 (minimum)
Cut at 3: [1, 2, 3] vs [] -> 1+2+3=6 vs 0, difference is 6
```

Input: `[1, 2, 4, 8, 14]`

```
Cut at 0: [] vs [1, 2, 4, 8, 14] -> 0 vs 1+2+4+8+14=29, difference is 29
Cut at 1: [1] vs [2, 4, 8, 14] -> 1 vs 2+4+8+14=28, difference is 27
Cut at 2: [1, 2] vs [4, 8, 14] -> 1+2=3 vs 4+8+14=26, difference is 23
Cut at 3: [1, 2, 4] vs [8, 14] -> 1+2+4=7 vs 8+14=22, difference is 15
Cut at 4: [1, 2, 4, 8] vs [14] -> 1+2+4+8=15 vs 14, difference is 1 (minimum)
Cut at 5: [1, 2, 4, 8, 14] vs [] -> 1+2+4+8+14=29 vs 0, difference is 29
```

Input: `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

```
Cut at 0: [] vs [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] -> 0 vs 1+1+1+1+1=5, difference is 5
Cut at 1: [1] vs [1, 1, 1, 1] -> 1 vs 1+1+1+1=4, difference is 3
Cut at 2: [1, 1] vs [1, 1, 1] -> 1+1=2 vs 1+1+1=3, difference is 1 (minimum)
Cut at 3: [1, 1, 1] vs [1, 1] -> 1+1+1=3 vs 1+1=2, difference is 1 (minimum)
Cut at 4: [1, 1, 1, 1] vs [1] -> 1+1+1+1=4 vs 1, difference is 3
Cut at 5: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] vs [] -> 1+1+1+1+1=5 vs 0, difference is 5
```

Comment: [Deleted sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18897/36445)

Comment: Can you add `[1, 2, 4, 8, 14] -> 4` to the test cases

Comment: Needs a worked example or two.

Comment: Uhh, why the close votes?

Comment: Didn't vote to close but there's a lack of clarity. You say *These are 0-indexed* but in your explanation say the correct output for the second element is `2`. Is that correct?

Comment: @Noodle9 2 is the index of the first element after the cut (i.e. the third element) (quoting: The position should be given as the index of the first element after the cut); I'll rewrite that slightly

Comment: @streetster You added a wall of text to the question without asking me. Please don't do that in the future.

Comment: sorry bud, was just trying to help - feel free to remove!

Comment: Can we assume that every element in the list will be greater than zero?

Comment: @Kaddath yes (the question also mentions that in the beginning)

Comment: Thanks, some say zero is both positive and negative, some say it's neither, the way I learnt we say "strictly positive" to avoid any confusion ;)

Comment: Might be interesting to repeat this challenge, only allowing negatives - that does increase complexity, particularly if your list is unordered.

Comment: @Kaddath If anyone does consider zero positive they are certainly in the extreme minority.  Positive is certainly a clear enough term, especially within this site where it has a solid precedent of meaning greater than zero.  The confusion usually occurs with the phrase *natural number*.

Answer (score 14):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>50</s> 35 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,*l:sum(l)>0and-~f(*l,-a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDNCoMwEITveYq9aSSC1h9aQV9EPKTYUCFGMemhiH11u1GIrRAI38zssMn4Ns9BJesqSsn7e8uBs0AW@tX7klYRV234EX4gWcjpah7aaCihJgB1zODCIGmYhWSDeAd0MnQ2KXWSBQZXTOVOO46riaPfHltypKNT/Bj/G8rdUHpqQCfbARe8ITekIUQME9inQae2WxeYGKdOGV94s1UWCCuY8R8s0MWj6xc)

#### Explanation

*If the sum of elements on the left of `a` is smaller than the sum of elements right of `a`, then the cut must be after `a`* - explanation by [Surculose Sputum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92237/surculose-sputum).

How I arrived here:

In each recursive call we compare `abs(sum(x[:i]) - sum(x[i:]))` to `abs(sum(x[:i+1]) - sum(x[i+1:]))`. If the first distance is larger, we continue with the next recursive call, if not the program is stopped:

```python
f=lambda x,i=0:abs(sum(x[:i])-sum(x[i:]))>abs(sum(x[:i+1])-sum(x[i+1:]))and f(x,i+1)
```

This can be shortened by modifying the list to make the distance calculation simpler:

```python
f=lambda x:abs(sum(x))>abs(sum(x[1:])-x[0])and 1+f(x[1:]+[-x[0]])
```

Even shorter if we take the input as single arguments:

```python
f=lambda a,*l:abs(sum(x)+a)>abs(sum(x)-a)and 1+f(*x,-a)
```

By rearranging the formula ...

$$ |(\sum_{k \in x}k) + a| > |(\sum_{k \in x}k) - a| \\
\iff ((\sum_{k \in x}k) + a)^2 > ((\sum_{k \in x}k) - a)^2 \\
\iff ((\sum_{k \in x}k) + a)^2 - ((\sum_{k \in x}k) - a)^2 > 0 \\
\iff 4 \cdot (\sum_{k \in x}k) \cdot a > 0 \\
\overset{a>0}\iff \sum_{k \in x}k > 0 $$

... we arrive at the final solution:

```python
f=lambda a,*x:sum(x)>0and-~f(*x,-a)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Took me a while to understand this, here's my attempt at an explanation: If the sum of elements on the left of `a` is smaller than the sum of elements right of `a`, then the cut must be after `a`. Otherwise, stop and returns the index of `a`.

Comment: @SurculoseSputum that is a nice explanation, I arrived there by rearranging some inequalities.

Answer (score 6):

## [K4](https://www.kx.com/download/) / [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>22</s> <s>18</s> 14 bytes

**Solution:**

```
*&(+\x)>|+\|x:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X0tNQzumQtOuRjumpsLKUMFIwUTBQsHQ5P9/AA)

**Explanation:**

Compare cumulative sum against reverse of the reverse cumulative sum.

```
*&(+\x)>|+\|x: / the solution
            x: / save input as x
           |x  / reverse
         +\    / cumulative sum 
        |      / reverse
       >       / greater than?
  (+\x)        / cumulative sum x
 &             / indices where true
*              / take first
```

Comment: What about for `[1 2 4 8 14]`? It seems that your current solution returns 3 when it should return 4

Comment: Ta, reverted :)

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 13 bytes

```
t&+gREqY*|&X<
```

The output is 0-indexed. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v0RNOz3ItTBSq0Ytwub//2hDBSMFEwULBUOzWAUA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L9ETTs9yLUwUqtGLcLmv0vI/2hDHQUjHQXjWK5oYzDLEMgCipkCxcB8EwgfxNJRsADKm0EEECgWAA).

#### Explanation

Consider input `[1 2 4 8 16]` as an example.

```
t    % Implicit input. Duplicate
     % STACK: [1 2 4 8 16], [1 2 4 8 16]
&+g  % All pair-wise additions, then convert to logical. Gives square matrix of ones
     % STACK: [1 2 4 8 16], [1 1 1 1 1;
                             1 1 1 1 1;
                             1 1 1 1 1;
                             1 1 1 1 1;
                             1 1 1 1 1]
R    % Upper triangular matrix. Sets elements below the diagonal to zero
     % STACK: [1 2 4 8 16], [1 1 1 1 1;
                             0 1 1 1 1;
                             0 0 1 1 1;
                             0 0 0 1 1;
                             0 0 0 0 1]
Eq   % Times 2, minus 1, element-wise
     % STACK: [1 2 4 8 16], [ 1  1  1  1  1;
                             -1  1  1  1  1;
                             -1 -1  1  1  1;
                             -1 -1 -1  1  1;
                             -1 -1 -1 -1  1]
Y*   % Matrix multiplication
     % STACK: [-29 -25 -17  -1  31]
|    % Absolute value, element-wise
     % STACK: [29 25 17 1 31]
&X<  % Index of minimum entry
     % STACK: 4
     % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>14</s> <s>12</s> 11 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @isaacg

```
lhoaysNsQ._
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PycjP7Gy2K84UC/@//9oQx0FIx0FEx0FCx0FQ5NYAA)

```
lhoaysNsQ._
         ._  All prefixes of input list
  o           Sort, using the following function as the key:
   a          Absolute difference of
     sN        - the sum of the prefix
    y              times 2
       sQ      - the sum of the input list
 h            First such prefix
l             Take its length 
(which gives the index of the element immediately after the prefix)
```

This is based on the following identity:

\$ \left|\sum_{b \in R} b - (\sum_{q \in Q} q - \sum_{b \in R} b) \right| = \left|2\sum_{b \in R} b - \sum_{q \in Q} q \right|\$

where \$R\$ is the current prefix and \$Q\$ is the input list.

Comment: You can save a byte by replacing `.m` by `o` and `b` by `N`. `.m` isn't needed if you're going to use `h` right afterwards.

Comment: @isaacg Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>65</s> 36 bytes

```hs
(0%)
a%(b:c)|a<sum c=1+(a+b)%c
a%_=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzX8NAVZMrUVUjySpZsybRprg0VyHZ1lBbI1E7SVM1GSgTb2vwPzcxM0/BViE3scA3XkGjoCgzr0RBTyFNk0tBQSFaIdpQx0jHOBbE0VGINgZyDGEcQx1THZCACaqAIbqAMbIAULmOhY6hGUIECsECsf//JaflJKYX/9eNcA4IAAA)

This answer really just uses one trick.  Instead of caluclating

$$
\left|a-b\right|
$$
and taking the minimum, go until the left hand side is greater than the right hand side.

To see why this works we will show that:

$$
  \left|a-(b+c)\right| < \left|(a+b)-c\right| \implies a > c
$$

Here is the proof:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\left|(a-c)-b \right| < \left|(a-c)+b \right| &\implies \\
a - c > 0 &\implies \\
a > c
\end{matrix}
$$

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ÄḤạSỤḢ
```

A monadic Link accepting a list which yields the first available cut index.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9qZWxsef//w4ThuKThuqFT4buk4bii////WzcsOCw0LDIsMV0)**

#### How?

```
ÄḤạSỤḢ - Link: list, X         e.g.  [ 7,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  6]
Ä      - cumulative sums (X)         [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 19]
 Ḥ     - double                      [14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 38]
   S   - sum (X)                     19
  ạ    - difference (vectorises)     [ 5,  3,  1,  1,  3,  5,  7, 19]
    Ụ  - grade                       [3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6, 7, 8]
     Ḣ - head                        3
```

Comment: This is very nice, but I think you should return *one* cut index.

Comment: Easily accommodated with one byte, but if this is a requirement you should probably change `If multiple correct outputs exist, you can output any.` to something like `If multiple correct outputs exist, you must output one`. ('any: used to refer to one or some of a thing or number of things, no matter how much or how many.')

Comment: ...and doable with 0 bytes :)

Comment: I guess I'll do that, but I have seen the exact sentence `If multiple correct outputs exist, you can output any` used to mean that very many times, and the test cases look like `[1, 5, 3, 2, 4] -> 2 or 3`, not `-> [2, 3]` (and the lead also asks for `such a position that` - I tried to word that to avoid this exact misunderstanding :( )

Comment: Fair enough. You did put "2 or 3" not "2 or 3 or [2,3]". I just read "any" and assumed it was fine.

Comment: That's now done at no cost.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 67 bytes

```python
lambda l:min([abs(sum(l)-2*sum(l[:i])),i]for i in range(len(l)))[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzdasQgEEbvfYohV1rMQn5aSiD7ItYLl03aAZ2I2sIS8uypupTCXMx3vjPjH@lro@Fc54/TGne7G7CTQ@LK3CKP345b0fYvdVETaiEk6nULgIAEwdDnwu1C2RJCdfpE57eQID4iY0WzSEsxM7jEdEeaGFgJhiLM4Izny4/JuWiX6C0m3rTXRggGIQtr/svAB6TE12a3B7RX2MMBag/znJ8cuhGn6iT0EgZd2p6pocauxo6V9jW3FY5/zvNklPCezbdKx0r/56n@Ag)

Straightforward implementation, can probably be golfed more. Output the 0-indexed cut.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>16</s> 13 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to Jonah

```
1 i.~+/\>+/\.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DRUy9eq09WPsgFjvvyaXAldqcka@QpqCoYKRgjGMYwzkGCJkTMECJshKTRQsFAzNECJQ@B8A)

Comment: Very nice, Galen

Comment: 13 bytes: `1 i.~+/\>+/\.`

Comment: @Jonah Thank you! My intention was to use suffix too, but apparently I went another direction :)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>64</s>  48 bytes

Now very similar to [ovs' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204215/58563), but we keep track of the left sum in \$s\$ rather than re-injecting the opposite values in the list.

```javascript
f=([v,...a],s=0)=>s<=eval(a.join`+`)&&1+f(a,s+v)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc3RCoIwFMbx@z3FuZKNrdnUoovWi8jAYRrK2AkXe/0lSoTl4bv88T@jjTa00/B8HTzeu5R6TesopJTWiKCPTN/CVXfROmrliINveMOyTPGeWhF4ZKlFH9B10uGD9rRWAgoBpYH1GIM8h4L8qHJRaqsU@W@d5tZiK/NpAU5Qkt23lYDLnD2blVY76rttML0B)

NB: `eval(a.join('+'))` is *undefined* if \$a[\:]\$ is empty, so `s<=eval(a.join('+'))` is always *false* in that case.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
η◄Ṁ≠½Σ¹∫
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fq1H8qKmxSPPQtv/ntj@a3vJwZ8OjzgWH9p5bfGjno47V////jzbUMdIxjuWKNgbShkDaUMdUB8Q2AbOBtI6FjqEZmAOFyBImsQA)

### Explanation

```
η◄Ṁ≠½Σ¹∫  Implicit input, say x = [5,2,2,3,6,2,6]
       ∫  Prefix sums: p = [5,7,9,12,18,20,26]
     Σ¹   Sum of x: 26
    ½     Halve: 13
  Ṁ≠      Absolute differences with elements of p: [8,6,4,1,5,7,13]
η◄        1-based index of minimal element: 4
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 55 bytes

```
Abs@ReplaceList[#,{x__,y__}:>Plus@x-Plus@y]~Ordering~1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773zGp2CEotSAnMTnVJ7O4JFpZp7oiPl6nMj6@1souIKe02KFCF0xVxtb5F6WkFmXmpdcZqv0PADJKFBzSo6sNdRSMdBSMa2O5EGLGYDFDFDGgOlOgOrCMCboMSExHwQKoxwxdCoFqY///BwA)

24 bytes saved @Kyle Miller
2 byte from my @pronoun is monicareinstate

Comment: 57 bytes using some pattern matching: https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X1nNwcG/KCW1KDMv3cExqdghKLUgJzE51SezuCRaWae6Ij5epzI@vtbKLiCntNihQhdMVcaq/Q8AailRcEiPrjbUUTDSUTCujeVCiBmDxQxRxIDqTIHqwDIm6DIgMR0FC6AeM3QpBKqN/f8fAA

Comment: 56 bytes by using the second argument of Ordering: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277378oJbUoMy892jGp2CEotSAnMTnVJ7O4JFpZp7oiPl6nMj6@1souIKe02KFCF0xVxuoYxqr9DwDqKlFwSI@uNtRRMNJRMK6N5UKIGYPFDFHEgOpMgerAMiboMiAxHQULoB4zdCkEqo39/x8A "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate I guess you accept this type of output since this is your challenge ;)

Comment: I have now noticed that `...~Ordering~1` works as well. (that type of output is valid because it's always a single integer, as far as I know)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 20 <sup>[SBCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBCS)</sup> bytes

```apl
(⊃∘⍸((+\⌽)≥(⌽+\))∘⌽)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X@NRV/OjjhmPendoaGjHPOrZq/moc6kGkNaO0dQESQBF/qcpPGqboECMUi6uR31TQYrTFAwVjBSMEVxjINcQWdYULGSCqsFEwULB0AxZDAr/AwA) Port of [streetster's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204219/75323) so be sure to upvote that one as well. This one is 1-indexed and returns the first option available.

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 29 <sup>[SBCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBCS)</sup> bytes

```apl
{0>+/1↓⍵:0⋄1+∇((-1∘↑),⍨1∘↓)⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v9rATlvf8FHb5Ee9W60MHnW3GGo/6mjX0NA1fNQx41HbRE2dR70rIOzJmkA1tf/TFB61TVAgWR8X16O@qSCdaQqGCkYKxgiuMZBriCxrChYyQdVgomChYGiGLAaF/wE) This is 0-indexed and returns the second option, when available. Fairly direct port of [ovs's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204215/75323) so be sure to upvote that answer as well!

Comment: Hah - was just about to ask whether porting mine would be shorter :)

Comment: @streetster yup; and I'm sure if I'm clever enough I can make your port even shorter :)

Comment: How'd you learn APL?

Comment: @S.S.Anne [APL Cultivations](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/52405/the-apl-orchard?tab=conversations) (chat-based bi-weekly lessons), asking a lot of questions over at the [APL Orchard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard) chatroom (and plenty of them answered by a very patient Adám) and [tackling problems](https://www.dyalogaplcompetition.com/?goto=welcome). Oh, and of course: banging my head against the wall a lot. Also, I am very much a newbie still!

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
ＩΣＥθ‹Σ…θ⊕κΣ✂θκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0V8M3sUCjUEfBJ7W4GMx3rkzOSXXOyAeLeuYlF6XmpuaVpKZoZGtqauoogJQE52Qmp4KkQUIgYP3/f3S0oY6CqY6CsY6CkY6CSWzsf92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. 0-indexed. Port of @ovs's solution, except that I include the current element in each sum as the sum of an empty list is `None`. Explanation:

```
   θ            Input aray
  Ｅ             Map over elements
         κ      Current index
        ⊕       Incremented
       θ        Input array
      …         Sliced to that index
     Σ          Take the sum
    ‹           Is less than
             κ  Current index
            θ   Input array
           ✂    Sliced starting at that index
          Σ     Take the sum
 Σ              Take the sum
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```apl
{(⊢⍳⌊/)|⍵+.×∘.(≤->)⍨⍳⍴⍵}
```

or

```apl
(|⍳⌊/∘|)∘.(≤->)⍨∘⍳∘⍴+.×⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqjUddix71bn7U06WvWfOod6u23uHpjzpm6Gk86lyia6f5qHcFSLZ3C1CqFqhFwVDBSMGYK03BGEgbcoH4pmC2CRdEzkTBQsHQDMyBQgA)

Using a variation on [*@LuisMendo*'s method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204224/65326).

**How?**

`⍳⍴⍵` gives the range `1 .. n` where `n` is the array size.

`∘.(≤->)⍨⎕` performs an outer product with `x≤y - x>y` (`1` for upper triangular, `-1` for lower)

`⍵+.×⎕` matrix-multiplies with the array

`|⎕` does absolute value, and

`⎕⍳⌊/⎕` searches the minimum index of the result

Answer (score 2):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 71 bytes

```lisp
(define(f a[s 0][n 0])(if(<(apply + a)s)n(f(cdr a)(+(car a)s)(+ n 1))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc6xCgIxDAbg3af4wcGULtZTcfBNDofQa6VYQmld7uk1d@ckTSAk@SCksn@F92efWZ6o20BTiEkCRfDYcHyMosVQinQnLiXPsGDTjFAkP1XtyZLnui7JQuCMht5JrWSes0BvHcjhhEFh9w@DguuBwwULnvuogBvcta@/XD75Ag)

1-indexed

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 8 bytes

Port of Zgarb's Husk answer. The index is 0-based.

```
ηOsO;αWk
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3Hb/Yn/rcxvDs///jzbVMQJCYx0zIGkWCwA)

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 12 bytes

```
āΣôćs˜OsOα}¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v8wNWFiMWX//8SBzqPDtMSHc8ucT3NPzrF9wqz//1szLCAxLCAyLCAzXQ)

## Explanation

```
ā            Length-range with the input.
 Σ           Sort by this:
  ô          Split input into chunks of current item.
   ć         Head extract,
    s        Put head in the back,
     ˜       Flatten.
      OsO    Sum head & tail.
         α}  Absolute difference between these parts.
           ¬ Take the first item of this sorting.
```

Comment: I like that 8-byter. I personally had this 9-byter in mind when I read the challenge: [`.œ2ùOÆÄWk`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f7@hko8M7/Q@3HW4Jz/7/P9pUxwgIjXXMgKRZLAA). :)

Comment: Here an alternative 8-byter based on the 6-byte Jelly answer (1-based indexing): [`.¥·IOαWk`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f79DSQ9s9/c9tDM/@/z/aVMcICI11zICkWSwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ḣJ§ạSH$iṂ$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9qZWxsef//4bijSsKn4bqhU0gkaeG5giT///9bMSwgMiwgNCwgOCwgMTZd)

#### How?

```
ḣJ§ạSH$iṂ$ - Main link (with input l, e.g. l = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16])
       iṂ$ - Get the index of the smallest element of
   ạ         - the absolute difference between
    SH$        - sum of elements in l divided by 2 and
ḣJ§            - for n in range(1, len(l)), get sum of the first n elements of l, e.g. [1, 3, 7, 15, 31]
```

Comment: Nice, welcome to CGCC! It turns out that my entry, `ÄḤạSİM`, is a golfed version of this. `ḣJ§` is `Ä`. Doubling the left, `ÄḤ`, saves the `$` used when halving the right, `SH$`. I also return all possible indices by finding the maximal indices, `M`, of the inverse values, `İ`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Interesting. I'm fairly new to Jelly, and there's some quirks that I didn't know, like the `Ä`. So thank you for your explanation!

Comment: It does take some time for most people, seems like you're off to a good start so keep going! Also note that there is [a chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57815/jelly-hypertraining) for getting better with Jelly (it's not very active, but is used).

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 60 bytes

```
func[a][s: 0 i: 1
while[(s: s + take a)<= sum a][i: i + 1]i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzLCsIwEEX3@YpLV4oIxlaRoH6E22EWoU1osC@aFj8/jtbHzObcw@WOrko3VxErb5D83JVkmaLBDsFAq0cdGkcrEREbTPbuYNfnC@LcQorSCeI1B06@H50ta0wuTiAFOdLYI@eFc2HNX3/AKxf87xU4QR9/4vOsmIYxdDLZ9k21rGfba@bfyIz0BA)

1-indexed

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) -aple, 39 bytes

```perl
my$i;@F=map{(++$i)x$_}@F;$_=$F[$#F/2-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@3UiXT2sHNNjexoFpDW1slU7NCJb7Wwc1aJd5WxS1aRdlN30jXMPb/f0MFIwVjLmMgachlqGCqAGKZcIFETRQsFAzNgEwo/JdfUJKZn1f8XzexIAcA)

...or 42 bytes:

```perl
sub f{my$i;@_=map{(++$i)x$_}@_;$_[@_/2-1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzNCoMwEITvPsVScogYKf6Voih5gd56kxBaiCVQqxgFRXx2u41iQ0hmv5nZVnXvZF3N8IRqrieiMy7z@tHO1POIdkciFy4zIksuz6EfiGUdjIK7Mn2a3ppOQY/S5EWSOVXTUQfwlCGDMmCAXyQE2xjOZWRZcLBoyyWYs058OPGxAdUVO5fD2pf/rxCOO1uvnihRY8uI/rRuzonMdgzk1fR5Rbl1NqoN/VFmG3BCmdoYWkhQ44vaVsAv7HzC7rJ@AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>101</s> 85 bytes

```hs
f x=snd$minimum$(`zip`[0..])$(\(a,b)->abs$sum a-sum b).(`splitAt`x)<$>[0..length x-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc9NCsIwEAXgvaeYRRYJpMVYFRe2IK57gjbYlFYN5qckKRQvX1N1ozMwi48Hj7kL/@iVmqUerAtwtiY4q9LSGtEBvlpXXsh8hSn3pkNaGqlHjXDzlENTrdOUE4RrLGhLkkK0HvlRg0iW25IUN35QMpxCM5EjKpa86s0t3GFKGJ@1kAZy6OwK4F0EVcXohmacRvlOlUVhP8Loji66/dMo9EDZ/o@/yzkgqCcPSfGpBBicNCFqfM9HcH0YnQFM5hc)

Less golfed:

```hs
minIndex f=snd.minimum.(`zip`[0..]).map f
f x = minIndex inner [0..length x-1]
  where 
    inner = (\(a, b)->abs$ sum a - sum b) . (`splitAt` x)
```

Comment: Your `let` could be replaced with a pattern guard. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc/LasMwEAXQfb9iAlpIMDJRk5YuEkPoOl9gm0TGTjNUDyPJYEL/3VUem2QGhsvZXOas429vzEx28CHBt3cpeFPsvdMd8JMP@4OYTzD9XTayWhaF6d1POsMkVbONrmOWHNnRMl6TLDnnNdfYClnqNrI4WtDyeltR8GMcDKVdOk5iw8qLWCwISdzybDU52ELn3wBunVBVCt9x1WCWx1SrLOpJFH7gVdcvmgW/UH2@8GObBhjUUwRZ3isBhkAuZc2fxgyhT2NwwMX8Dw "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Also I'm not sure why you map across `z` just to index by `i`.  Since `z` is just a range of numbers this is the same as applying the function to `i` directly which saves a lot of bytes and gets rid of the need for `let` altogether.

Comment: changed it to a zip which I think is what you were getting at but looks like you had a better idea!

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>58</s> 49 bytes

Uses a variable declaration via `is` to avoid declaring a proper body and having to type the excessively long word `return`.

For some reason List has the method `FindIndex`, but other `IEnumerable`s don't seem to.

```cs
a=>0is var s?a.FindIndex(e=>(s+=e)>a.Sum()-s+e):0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpds45NZXGKTmVdip6MAIhXcFGz/J9raGWQWK5QlFikU2yfquWXmpXjmpaRWaKTa2mkUa9umatol6gWX5mpo6hZrp2paGfy35uIKKALq13DTyEstj46tNtRRMNJRMK7VC8kH2aChqalpjabEGKzEEJ8SoCmmQFPACk0IKAQp0VGwAJpoRkAlAhFtJPGWm6Oo/A8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 112 bytes

```c
l;r;f(int n,char**m){char*i=*(m+1),*j=i;while(*j++);for(j-=2,r=l=0;i<=j;)l<r?l+=*i++:(r+=*j--);return i-*(m+1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7LDoIwFET3fEWjMenTCO68VH@EDRaQ25RirhBJjN9eUXcnk8mZcebmXEoBCDqOcWJRu74mKQfx@gFayQeVCy29RXj2GFouvVICupG4N7bQZIM9AJbWgwglXYKyEpU6cVrBGyOA2mmmyND8XfBOW4wuzE3LysfU4Ljvz9lQY/xdqDX7TjMpr@KVMXanNe34ZtdUcaNZx9fCVQjI3ilVS14tRbUcPw)

Unfortunately I did not figure out how to input hex characters as arguments into the program with the online view.
Basically the input consists of a single "argument" which is the array of numbers.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf SE! We're glad to have you.

Looking over this answer, I'm struggling to make sense of it. Admittedly, I'm no C expert, but perhaps a brief explanation of what the arguments and return value are might be in order. If you want to provide an example of your code in action, check out [Try It Online](https://tio.run/#c-gcc), created by our very own Dennis; it makes writing, testing, and sharing code very easy, even to the point of copying an entire well-formatted Code Golf SE submission to your clipboard automatically!

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out to me - i updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>69</s> 66 bytes

```
f(l)=L[∑_{n=1}^Ll[n]>=∑_{k=L}^{L.max}l[k]][1]
L=[1...l.length]
```

Returns 1-based indices. Uses the same strategy as ovs's [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204215/96039)

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/f3rgr4ssrl)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lcdrfv9u9a)

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 117 bytes

```scala
def g(l:List[Int],s:Int,i:Int):Int={val h::t=l;if(t==Nil)i else if(s+h>t.sum)if(s<l.sum)i+1 else i else g(t,s+h,i+1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question deserved a lengthy suboptimal PHP answer, that has to cope with the fact that the arguments array starts with the script name, forcing me to add the `$i>1` test that leads to extra brackets, and such oddities..

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 124 bytes

```php
$f=array_sum;$g=array_slice;for($a=$argv;$a[++$i];$s=$r)if(($s<$r=abs($f($g($a,$i))-$f($g($a,0,$i))))&$i>1)break;echo($i-2);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcpRCsIwEEXRzTwkQy2Y0g8hTV2IiExLkgaVhgkKrn4sgv5cOHDLUnQ4la2InkX4fa3Ph0P64Z7n4OIqBuzBkl4OfG4a5ItD9RDK0RjUAeJ5qgbRIG3vHpmo/evwNdEOebQ0SeCbC/OyGuS2I6eqVjvt9ai2/wA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 84 bytes

```java
a->{int i=0,j=a.length-1,l=0,r=0,t;for(;i<j;)t=l<r?l+=a[i++]:(r+=a[j--]);return-~i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZAxa8MwEIX3/IojYLAbWTRthhLFKVkKHTqlW/BwTWxXriwZ6RwIwf3rrmynLaQFHdK9d@J7XIlHjMvDRyer2liC0ve8Ian4jZj80fJG70ka/a/pyGZY9dZeoXPwglLDeQJQN29K7sERkr@ORh6g8l64JSt1sUsBbeGiYRTg1TxrerpwVlLTLl1DnnQYr8@@A5ncsjJBrjJd0Hs8Z8oL1heJ3NhQyFUpIkrUyj6qWYI7OZuly9D2zzKO00jYjBqr408p2k4MyAHiY1DmyEFyCQJwhjmDOwb30LIracHggcF8ceX8nm@jHRF9tCPaAbEcQdEPZ3tylFXcNMRrvxHKw2nglhAcAj1lsLEWT46TGdcV9p8jBjnHulanjfPrGrVoRLWTvtruCw)

### Credits

- -1 byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

Comment: [82 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZBRa8IwFIXf/RUXQWhtGnTzYRjj8GWwhz25t9KHzLYuXZqU5FYQ6f56l7ZuAzdICPecXL7DKcVJxGX20cmqNhah9DNtUCo6Z5M/WtHoA0qj/zUd2lxUvXVQwjl4EVLDZQJQN29KHsChQP@cjMyg8l6wRyv1MUlB2KMLh68Ar@ZZ49OVs5Eak3QLBe9EvL34CSRfkJILqnJ9xPd4SZQXLF@wwtiAyU3JQhtxtbGPgYq4SGQUpeF8sRZJGccpszk2VsefkrUdG4ADwofA3KEDfo0BcIElgTsC99CSG2lF4IHAcnXj/J5vox0RfbSTsANiPYLCH87@7DCvqGmQ1r4PLILpzK1hls30lMDOWnF2FM1YVtAvhwQKKupanXfOlzVq4YhqJ/1tuy8 "Java (JDK) – Try It Online")